# How to include automatically generated custom URLs in sitemap.xml in wordpress using yoast?

Tags: xml, wordpress, sitemap, yoast

My site has custom URLs generated automatically after users post their used car details for sale. How to include these URLs in yoast sitemap.xml.

URL generated: https://www.carsangrah.com/used_car/Tamil%20Nadu/Chennai/Maruti-Suzuki-S-Cross-DDiS-200%20Zeta_844

generated sitemap: https://www.carsangrah.com/sitemap_index.xml

this sitemap doesn't include above generated URL.
Please suggest me the right way to include these URLs.

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but you can add append text to the Yoast sitemap using 'wpseo_sitemap_index' (http://hookr.io/filters/wpseo_sitemap_index/), which also includes appending XML markup.

Example:

```html
<?php

function _add_custom_items(){
  
  $appended_text = '';
  
  $post_id = 1; //Use whatever method to get your post info
  $your_post = get_post($post_id);
  $your_post_link = get_permalink($post_id);

  $appended_text .= '<sitemap>' . 
                  '<loc>' . $your_post_link . '</loc>' .
                  '<lastmod>' . str_replace(' ', 'T', $your_post->post_modified) . '+00:00</lastmod>' . 
                '</sitemap>';
  }

  return $appended_text;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_index', '_add_custom_items' );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Yoast plugin, I dont think that you will be able to add custom URL in your sitemap.

But you can use [Google XML Sitemaps](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/) plugin which will allows you to add your custom link in site map.

Here is the detail [explanation](https://www.dailytechtuts.com/624/add-custom-page-in-sitemap/) of how to add custom URL in sitemap.

Comment: This is good for few URLs and need to be done manually for each URL. Is there any way, it can be done automatically for each URL generated.

Comment: Hope this [URL](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/add-external-sitemap-to-index/) will help you to add multiple custom URL in sitemap.